# Cambiar las Keys de los objetos de un arreglo

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en `ReactJs` y quier utilizar `react-select`: https://react-select.com/

Segun entendí, tengo que pasar un arreglo de objetos, donde cada objeto debera tener una  `key value` y otra  `key label`,

**Value:** corresponde al valor seleccionado, la mejora practica es utilizar el campo `id`.

**Label:** justamente la etiqueta que va indicar que valor seleccionado, en mi caso voy a utilizar el campo `name`.

Ejemplo de lo que acepta `react-select`:

```javascript
const reactSelectArray= [
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla', rating: 'safe' },
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate', rating: 'good' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry', rating: 'wild' },
  { value: 'salted-caramel', label: 'Salted Caramel', rating: 'crazy' },
];
```

Como pueden observar, cada objeto tiene una `key id`y otra key label

Desde mi API estoy obtentiendo un arreglo de la siguente manera:

```json
     [ 
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Sipes LLC",
            "departaments": [],
            "created_at": "2020-10-31T20:14:57.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-10-31T20:14:57.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Nienow LLC",
            "departaments": [],
            "created_at": "2020-10-31T20:14:57.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-10-31T20:14:57.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Halvorson-Feil",
            "departaments": [],
            "created_at": "2020-10-31T20:14:57.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-10-31T20:14:57.000000Z"
        }
    ]
```

Del arreglo `arregloApi` quiero poder transformalo a de la siguente manera:

```javascript
const arregloApiFormateado = [
        {
            value: 1,
            label: "Sipes LLC"
        },
        {
            value: 2,
            label: "Nienow LLC"
        },
        {
            value: 3,
            label: "Halvorson-Feil"
        }
    ]
```

Luego el arreglo `arregloApiFormateado` lo paso a la `prop` `options` y `react-select` hace el resto de la "magia"

No estoy logrando correctamente dicha transformacion, me falta mucha practica para manipar arreglos de objetos. Si alguen me puede dar una pista seria de mucha ayuda, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que esto es lo que buscas, lo que hice fue recorrer lo que recibes y pasarlo a un arreglo de la manera que deseas, espero te ayude.

```js
var api = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Sipes LLC",
    "departaments": [],
    "created_at": "2020-10-31T20:14:57.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-31T20:14:57.000000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Nienow LLC",
    "departaments": [],
    "created_at": "2020-10-31T20:14:57.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-31T20:14:57.000000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Halvorson-Feil",
    "departaments": [],
    "created_at": "2020-10-31T20:14:57.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-31T20:14:57.000000Z"
  }
];
var arreglo = [];
var x = {
  objArray1: {},
  objArray2: {}
};
for (var i in api) {

  var item = api[i];
  arreglo.push({
    "value": item.id,
    "label": item.name,
  });
}
console.log(arreglo)
```

Comment: Perfecto!. Me funciono. Muchas gracias. Hago otra consulta porahi me podes ayudar, esta informacion la traigo de una API con laravel, la mejor practira es hacer esto o generar otro EntryPoint que solamente me entregue los datos reducidos?

Comment: Creo que si lo usaras solo para eso, seria mejor generar uno que te traiga la data que necesitas.

Answer (score 2):

Se que ha pasado mucho tiempo desde esta pregunta, pero dejaré esto por acá para otras personas que busquen una solución a esto. Creo que es mejor ocupar las funciones nativas de javascript para recorrer un arreglo y re-mapearlo

```js
var api = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Sipes LLC",
    "departaments": [],
    "created_at": "2020-10-31T20:14:57.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-31T20:14:57.000000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Nienow LLC",
    "departaments": [],
    "created_at": "2020-10-31T20:14:57.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-31T20:14:57.000000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Halvorson-Feil",
    "departaments": [],
    "created_at": "2020-10-31T20:14:57.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-31T20:14:57.000000Z"
  }
];

const arregloApiFormateado = api.map(({id, name}) => ({value: id, label: name}))

console.log(arregloApiFormateado)
```